# Why when initiating $.click() several times, and if the link is clicked once, it captures it more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, buttonclick

I have something like:

```
function init(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    //do something;
  }
}
```

And when new content is added via ajax, I'm calling `init()`, so that click event applies to new buttons. But when I click it once, it captures several clicks (as many times as I called `init()`). It makes sense, but how to avoid it?

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/s2ZAz/8/

**Solutions:**
* Use $.delegate() - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ 
* Use $.live() - http://api.jquery.com/live/
Less preferred, but still, solutions:
* Use $.off() - http://api.jquery.com/off/ or $.unbind() - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` says, "for every object matching the selector, hook up this click listener". You probably want something more like `delegate` that says "for every object that will ever match this selector, hook up this listener".

```
$(document).delegate('button', 'click', function() {
});
```

You will still get double callbacks if you call `init` twice, but in this manner, you won't *have* to call `init` twice, because as new objects are added, they'll already be assigned to click listeners.

Note that `document` above should be replaced with the nearest persistent ancestor, as per Greg's comment below.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DwLTr/).

Since jQuery 1.7, you can preferably use [the `.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to achieve the same effect.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DwLTr/1/).

Comment: Upvoted, but it might be worth mentioning that delegate is generally preferred assuming some containing element is known to always be present. The live method, which just calls delegate on the document, can be pretty overkill.

Comment: This doesn't improve over .live() yet because you're still delegating to the document. You should delegate to the nearest ancestor that contains all clickable nodes and is not expected to be destroyed.

Comment: @Greg: Good point. I'd argue `delegate` still has a couple of advantages over `live` when it comes to consistency of the functions, etc, but no further clues about the DOM can be inferred from the question. I added a note about it tho.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unbind` method to remove the event handler (or the `off` method if you're using the new jQuery 1.7 syntax for attaching handlers)

Better yet, you can use the `live` method, to set up the event handler for any elements that are added to the page in the future and match the given selector. In this way you only have to call init once.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").delegate("button", "click", function() {
    alert('I\'m annoying!');
});

$('div').append("<button>Click me, I will alert twice</button><br/>");

$('div').append("<button>Click me, I will alert once</button><br/>");

$('div').append("<button>Click me, I will not alert at all</button><br/>");
```

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/s2ZAz/9/)

Comment: so it's same as .live('click')? never knew about delegate(); cool, thanks!

Comment: @shershams Yes, except that it won't be deprecated in 1.7 and it supports root element other than the whole document.

Comment: @GregPettit why would I copy-paste it if question was given as jsfiddle? I make a simple change and save it. That is a lot simpler than explaining what to do, when any smart person can google the function changed and see API doc for himself.

Comment: That is quite a poor answer... what if jsfiddle is down? You should explain the solution in words as well.

Comment: @FelixKling the answer is poor because jsfiddle may go down? This is Q&A forum, not a wiki.

Comment: Please have a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @FelixKling yes, and the main point there that link must be the actual answer, which in this case it is. Sorry if you don't like it.

Comment: The main point is *[...] links are fantastic, but they should **never** be the only piece of information in your answer.*, which is the case here. Anyway I just wanted to give a suggestion how to improve your answer. If you don't want to, fine for me.

Comment: @FelixKling and then he explains why, which is the part that I noted. I personally don't see whats the big deal with improving answers. If it helps the OP, then good. If not - oh well, I tried. Besides the question is answered and case closed. At this point your concern sounds like nitpicking at something that isn't even relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by David, and as per liho's delegate example (loved the way the fiddle cascaded how many times the alert would pop!!), the problem is with multiple bindings, which can be solved with `.live()` (deprecated) or `.delegate()` (being phased out), or `.on()` (the preferred). However, it is a mistake to delegate listening to the document or even `body` node in terms of performance.

A better way to do this is identify an ancestor of the button that will not ever be destroyed. `body` is an easy choice, but it's almost always the case that we build our pages with wrapper elements of some sort, which are nested one or more levels deeper than `body` and therefore allow you to set fewer listeners.

HTML:

```
<div id="someWrapper">
  <div class="somethingThatGetsDestroyed">
    <button>Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS using jQuery 1.7+:

```
$('#someWrapper').on('click', 'button', function() {
  alert('Clickity-click!');
});
```